# What is Microsoft's official stance on using WCF with Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

I noticed last night that the WCF extensions for Visual Studio 2005 aren't available on their site any longer.  I've read that they want people to use Visual Studio 2008 for WCF/WF/WPF.

Have they made an official statement regarding this?

edit:

I already have the CTP3 for VS2005.  I want to know what Microsoft's **official** stance is.  Yes, I've read the threads and the blogs.  If a blog post is all that is needed to make it official then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem... I needed to use WCF from Visual Studio 2005 and when I installed VS2008 the WCF extensions were gone.
I googled around a lot and I found a hack to being able of working with WCF in Visual Studio 2005 or 2008.

You have to run the following command from a VS2005 command promtp: ***msiexec /i vsextwfx.msi WRC_INSTALLED_OVERRIDE=1***

For a little more info take a look at the post I wrote about it here: http://sgomez.blogspot.com/2008/08/visual-studio-2005-extensions-for-wcf.html

Answer (score -1):

There was never anything but CTP released for MS Visual Studio 2008

According to [this](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3695753&SiteID=1) thread MS wants you to move to Visual Studio 2008.

This [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/acangialosi/archive/2008/06/27/vs-2005-extensions-for-net-framework-3-0-wpf-wcf-ctp-is-coming-off-the-ms-download-center.aspx) post confirms that.

You could still download the [CTP3 for Visual Studio 2005](http://www.download.com/The-Visual-Studio-2005-extensions-for-NET-Framework-3-0-WCF-WPF-November-2006-CTP/3000-10253_4-10727672.htm) from a third-party server

Comment: EVERY question could be found by googling, eventually.  Take it easy on the little guy.  He isn't even over 1000 yet.

Comment: @Will:  LOL.I've had the CTP3 installed on my machine for over a year.If you read my initial post you would realize that I probably had googled it.All I'm asking about is there was any _official_ statement made.And the reason I haven't reached 1000 is because I spend more time working than on SO.